# Routes 'break' when additional UrlParameter is added

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My application works well.

In my View, I have a link which points to MyProducts controller (all logic removed to keep post tidy)

This looks like

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string product, string gender)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { product = product, gender = gender });
    }
```

And in my HomeController I have

```
    public ActionResult Index(string product, string gender)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = product;

        return View();
    }
```

and in my View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyProduct", FormMethod.Get))
{ 
    <input name="product" /><br />
    <input name="gender" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Simple as that. It works great.

If I use the following route table

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{product}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", product = UrlParameter.Optional}
       );
```

everything works fine and when I search for a product, the URL renders as

```
www.mysite.com/Home/Index/Shoes
```

However, I need to be able to filter by the gender, such as shoes for men or shoes for ladies.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{product}/{gender}/",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", product = UrlParameter.Optional, gender = UrlParameter.Optional}
       );
```

This kills my nice routing, when I perform the search with both parameters, instead of showing me the desired URL like

```
www.mysite.com/Home/Index/Shoes/Ladies
```

It is in fact showing

```
www.mysite.com/Home/Index/?product=Shoes&gender=Ladies
```

I cannot see what I've done wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make multiple routes, multiple optional params in a row will cause the url generator to use parameters

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    name: "GenderOptional", 
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{product}/{gender}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", gender = UrlParameter.Optional } 
); 

routes.MapRoute( 
    name: "Default", 
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{product}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", product = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```